# Modifying/updating grails config on runtime

Tags: grails, groovy

Since lots of config in grails were placed at `grailsApplication.config`, lets say if i have a secure management page for managing and updating properties. Should i directly modify those configuration properties directly? Is it a good practice to do so? Im taking this into consideration:

- the app should be scalable. Multiple instance of the same app will be deployed.
- i will use an application servlet to deploy my app, e.g. wildfly
- i will use hazelcast for session, etc

Can you guys share your experience in this?

Comment: No, it's not a good practice to modify those run-time in a deployed production environment. It's better to build your own centralized configuration (likely kept in some persistent data source). You might even consider a stand alone micro-service that manages only this that your other applications talk to in real-time via REST/HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, i guess your suggestions is to place in a secured db and maybe have publish/subscribe events when any of the instance updates the config properties after persisting it to db? What do you think?

Comment: You might try to externalize your configuration and reload it whenever it changes, http://www.tothenew.com/blog/externalize-and-reload-grails-log4j-configuration/